# Apps installed via Snap Store don't launch (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: sudo, snap, killall

I have a problem with the Ubuntu 22.04.1 snap store. In fact, every time I install an application using snap store, I can't use it, i.e. whenever I want to launch the application that I have installed, it does not open. I don't understand why this is happening. And yet Snap Store works normally, but the applications I install using it does not.

Comment: Try launching a snap application from the terminal. Error messages may reveal what is wrong, e.g. "snap run firefox" to run a snap install of firefox. The name of a program appears in the first column of "snap list". Copy any output from the terminal into your question: use "edit".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `snapd` was not installed. Opening the terminal and running: `sudo apt install snapd` worked for me.

Comment: Some additional details could make this a more useful answer ;-).  First, do you have any idea why `snapd` wasn't installed?  This should (I would expect) be fairly unusual, since it's a default package, right?  Also, in your case, were you able to *install* Snaps from the Store without `snapd` installed?  I wouldn't expect that part to work either, but I could certainly be wrong about.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Not sure why it wasn't installed. I am using a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I don't recall uninstalling it, but I guess I must've inadvertently done so. I was able to install and use Snaps from the Store for a week or so and then this issue arose (probably due to me accidentally uninstalling 'snapd'). Anyways, just wanted to add the answer in case others had a similar situation.